# rxjs-tslint vs rxjs-tslint-rules packages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, tslint

I used to use [`rxjs-tslint-rules`](https://cartant.github.io/rxjs-tslint-rules/) package to be aware of RxJS-related issues in my projects. It was added to `devDependencies` section of my projects' `package.json` files.

Now, there is [`rxjs-tslint`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint) package which adds a few more rules specific to RxJS 6 and `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate` tool.

After migration, if I still want those

- `rxjs-collapse-imports`
- `rxjs-pipeable-operators-only`
- `rxjs-no-static-observable-methods`
- `rxjs-proper-imports`

rules to be checked by TSLint, do I need to add them to my `tslint.json` and `rxjs-tslint` package to my `devDependencies`? Or `rxjs-tslint` package is intended to be a one time migration assistant and rules it currently provides are covered by the bigger `rxjs-tslint-rules` package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment, `rxjs-tslint` is intended to be used as one-time migration mechanism to upgrade a RxJS v5 codebase to v6. Its distribution installs some scripts into `node_modules/.bin` to facilitate this.

However, there is nothing to stop you from installing `rxjs-tslint` as a `devDependency`. If you do, you would also reference it from your `tslint.json` file, just as you would with `rxjs-tslint-rules`. Like this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "rxjs-tslint",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules"
  ],
  "rules": {
  }
}
```

Like [`rxjs-tslint-rules`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/blob/v4.1.1/index.js), [`rxjs-tslint` is unopinionated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint/blob/0.1.0/index.js) and no rules are enabled by default. So if you want the rules listed in your question to be enabled, you will need to configure them in the file's `rules` setting.

I'm the author of `rxjs-tslint-rules` and I've had some conversations with the developers of the `rxjs-tslint` package. It's likely that, sometime soon, some of the rules from my package will be included in `rxjs-tslint` - to represent what's considered to be best practice. Until then - and perhaps afterwards - you can use rules from both packages.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and insider information especially! It seems that `rxjs-tslint` would become an official TSLint rule set some time in the future and `rxjs-tslint-rules` would extend its rules set.